# How to load remote proto definitions using proto-loader in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node

Url for RPCs is `flow-testnet.g.alchemy.com:443`

I don't have any `.proto` files locally.

How do I load them to generate package definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Reflection API concept exact for this purpose.
Loader implementation can be found here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc-reflection-js